# What’s the difference between meminisse and memini?

Tags: verbs, meaning, morphology, motto

I’d love to get a tattoo saying ‘remember’ in Latin, but would rather not use memento. Would it be possible to either use *meminisse* or *memini*? I’d like remember to be like a reminder for myself to remember how I felt at a particular moment in the past. Hope this makes sense!

Comment: Welcome to the site, and nice question! This has to do with verb conjugations. It could help write a more customized answer if you tell us whether you speak any languages other than English

Comment: i have a question too. is there any way to differentiate "i don't remember, i won't/ can't/ wouldn't". i learned there aren't modal verbs in latin but i wanna tattoo from these, so...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are different forms of the same verb.
Here are some of the over 30 forms:

- *meminisse* = "to remember"
- *memini* = "I remember"
- *meminimus* = "we remember"
- *meminerunt* = "they remember"
- *memineram* = "I remembered"
- *memento!* = "remember!"
- *meminero* = "I will remember"

The form you need depends on what you want to say.
Is it the statement "I/you/we/… remember", an order "remember!", a description of the action "to remember", a wish "I wish I remembered" (different forms for real and irreal), or something else?
Also, you might want to consider adding more words, like "we remember her" or "I will remember myself".

Both *meminisse* and *memini* are possible, but they mean different things and there are plenty of other forms of the same verb.
If you have found something you want to say in the text, please ask a new question to find how to phrase it in Latin.
Remember that when translating short phrases like the ones one would see in a tattoo or a coat of arms, it is not enough to give the English phrase, but you should also describe what is the message you want to convey.

Comment: This one is missing: Meminisses = It means "Remembering"....or "I hold in memory"

Comment: @DiGascon I converted your reply to a comment since it doesn't endeavor to answer the question. But I want to point out that neither translation is correct. *Meminisses* is 2nd person singular ("you") pluperfect subjunctive, which, because it is a defective verb, means something like "you might have remembered" or "you should have remembered" (depending on the surrounding grammar, of course).

Comment: @cmw And perhaps more importantly, my answer is explicitly giving only a sample of the many forms. It's missing way more than one form, and with every intention.