# "Non est malus recordari, sed vivere autem meminisses, est"

Tags: latin-to-english-translation

How would you translate this to English?

> "Non est malus recordari, sed vivere autem meminisses, est". (No es malo recordar, pero vivir de recuerdos lo es).

The sentences come from [this tweet](https://twitter.com/ssk_josue?lang=en). I especially want to know what is the meaning of "meminisses."

Comment: Welcome to the site! Can you tell us where the phrase is from? Context helps, and in many cases there already is a good translation somewhere out there.

Comment: I'm a bit confused by the question: the Spanish phrase is perfectly good and easily translated into English (Spanish->English). The Latin phrase is botched. Are you looking for a good Latin translation of the Spanish expression, or an English translation of the Spanish phrase?

Comment: Why are only moderators allowed to answer?

Comment: @Cairnarvon That opening probably has to do with the OP's answer with related content to another question. A moderator converted that answer into a comment.

Comment: Hola! Bienvenido a Latín.SE! No se entiende muy bien lo que quieres preguntar. ¿Quieres validar la traducción al latín de esa frase en castellano? Yo te puedo ayudar a traducir al inglés sí ese es el problema. Por ejemplo, la oración en cuestión podría ser: _it's not bad to remember, but to live from memories is_. _Malo_ también puede ser _wrong_, si quieres enfatizar lo incorrecto: _it's not wrong to remember..._

Comment: Hello guys, Thanks for your replies. As Joonas mentioned, this question has to do with "an answer with related content to another question. A moderator converted that answer into a comment." The whole thing has to do with the "exact" English definition of the word MEMINISSES (apreciaría mucho tu ayuda Rafael) I would very much appreciate your input guys. BTW, the phrase came from here: twitter.com/ssk_josue?lang=en Thanks

Comment: The Latin generally and the specific word *meminisses* are grammatically wrong, so they can't really be translated.

Answer (score 3):

As brianpck notes in the comments, the Latin is ungrammatical. It looks like someone tried to use a word-for-word translation on the Spanish to get the Latin to make it sound "loftier." But that doesn't work.

For one, *meminisses* is not the same as *recuerdos*, but as I mention [here](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/6866/what-s-the-difference-between-meminisse-and-memini#comment35235_6867), it's 2nd singular pluperfect subjunctive active. It's a verb, but *recuerdos* (in this sentence) is a plural noun.

The word *autem* for *de* is also just wrong. *Autem* would instead come after the first word in the clause (it's post-positive) and would correspond to *pero*, but *sed* is doing performing that function already.

Finally, *malus* is masculine, but the Latin would require a neuter here. (It's "it is not wrong," not "he is not wrong.")

If that Twitter user wanted to translate the Spanish more accurately, he could have written it this way:

> Malum non est meminisse, sed vivere in memoriis est malum

Or if you wanted to use *recordari*, you could have that word instead:

> Malum non est recordari, sed vivere in recordationibus est malum.

Comment: Resumen: la gramática del latín está mal. P.ej. _meminisses_ es _hubieras recordado_ (no _recuerdos_). _Sed_ y _autem_ son mutuamente redundantes (y el segundo queda mal posicionado). En vez de _malus_ debe decir _malum_ (neutro en vez de m.) [Después vienen las dos propuestas de traducción al latín].

Comment: I'd prefer starting with the negation for emphasis, autem over sed, and omitting the second malum (but it's all a matter of taste): _non est malum meminisse, vivere autem in memoriis est_. [Prefiero comenzar con la negación para dar énfasis, autem más que sed y omitir el segundo malum, pero es cosa de gustos...]